# Why isn't fs.writeFile creating the file even though no errors? (Heroku)

Tags: node.js, express, child-process, fs

I'm executing a command in a child_process.exec in an express route -- the service works perfectly locally but once I deploy it to Heroku the fs.writeFile does not work (that is, everything works fine without errors but I can't find the file). I even put a fs.existsSync in the callback and it returns true (!) -- why can't I find it when I run heroku run bash and explore the directory via that shell CLI? The write is being done in an express like below:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = router
.get('/data', (req, res, next) => {
    exec('npm run get', { cwd: __dirname }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${err}`);
            return;
        }
        var truncated = stdout.split("...");
        var trunc = truncated[1].split("\n");
        var name = Date();
        fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/data/${name}.txt`, trunc, function (err, written, string) {
         console.log(fs.existsSync(`${__dirname}/data/${name}.txt`));
         if (err) throw err;
         res.json(trunc.slice(1, 11));
        });
    });
}):
```

I tried write, writeSync, also tried a stream -- all same issue. Something to do with fs being used in a childprocess on a remote server?

Comment: You get the result of `console.log(${__dirname}/data/${name}.txt)`, then access that same location via bash and the file is not there? Even when `fs.existsSync` is returning true?

Comment: exactly -- in the heroku logs it logs the request, then:
2017-07-11T01:14:26.080519+00:00 app[web.1]: true
and the response:
2017-07-11T01:14:26.082940+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /api/data 200 2594.517 ms - 196
then if i heroku run bash it's not there ..

Comment: I also tried running the command given to exec directly in the heroku bash shell and that works, file is created and locatable in in the CLI -- so it's definitely something with the route/exec where the file isn't sticking, or something

Comment: Just checking. Isn't a possibility that your express are running on a different machine instance? If you create a file via bash on that location `${__dirname}/data/`, your express is able to return true when `fs.existsSync` on it?

Comment: that's it -- i tried creating a file in the heroku run bash shell and it wasn't there after I closed the shell and ran run bash again. express was also returning false. heroku says these are "one-off dynos" -- how would then would i make additions/changes to the app's fs from express on my heroku backend? or: if the changes are in fact being made, is there a way to directly view the updated fs?

Comment: seems you can't use node's fs functions to manipulate the fs in heroku as you are not deployed to "a" server but to a system of dynos. still, it seems like it would/should be possible to edit the fs, unless heroku takes a snapshot of the app's directory upon deploy and that's only changeable by another deploy.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know.